# ITelemetry.InstrumentationKey is empty

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am trying to set the InstrumentationKey of AppInsights TTelemetry from appsettings.json.  My code looks like this

Program.cs

```
 WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
               {
                   config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
               });
```

Startup.cs, ConfigureServices()

```
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
```

appsettings.json

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "[my key]"
  },
```

However, when I run _serviceProvider.GetService(), or recieved the TelemetryClient via dependecy injection in the controller, the telemetry.Context.InstrumentationKey is empty.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

`TelemetryClient.InstrumentationKey or TelemetryClient.Context.InstrumentationKey` should be empty unless you explicitly set it there as an override of what is in configuration.

As mentioned above, explicitly set it like: `TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey= "your_ikey" };`, then you can use .Context.InstrumentationKey to get the key.

And you can find the details on this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/141#issuecomment-197623921).

Hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't many sense.  TelemetryClient instance is being created by dependency injection.  I'm not creating an instance of it.  It is supposed to pick the key from Configuration.

Comment: If you have any concern, you can comment on that [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/141) I mentioned, or submit a new issue on [application insights GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues).

Comment: Agreed that this makes no sense.  Configured app insights with an instrumentation key and using the provider.GetService<TelemetryClient>() has no key set.  How does it get set when injecting into controllers?  new TelemetryClient() is obsoleted now so this seems wrong...

Comment: "This is by design" :D.. well this is a bad design.